# Read array values in file with pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a csv file with an array values in one columns. You can see the data [here (drive link)](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1E-BVkxaybQfO0Lu6RBuudFfOHXHVgfAV/view?usp=sharing).

I use this code `df = pd.read_csv('class_ 0_0_data.csv', sep=",")` and if you check with `df.dtypes` all the columns are in object type. How do you change this into float?

I tried using `df['CpuTemperature'] = df['CpuTemperature'].astype(float)` but it return

> could not convert string to float

I tried using `df['CpuTemperature'] = pd.to_numeric(df['CpuTemperature'],errors='coerce')` but it return all the values to NaN.

Anyone know how to read the file into usable values? I also want to change all the columns from object to float, not only the CpuTemperature. Thank you!

Edit: Expected result, something like this, so I can use the value from every elements in the array, for example, to make a plot.

```
|     |    CpuTemperature     |
|     |  0  |  1  |  2  |  3  |
| --- | ----------------------|
| 0   |56.75|44.75|3.52 |47.83|
| 1   |48.75|42.25|2.39 |45.00|
```

so far, I use `df = pd.read_csv('class_ 0_0_data.csv', converters={'class_ 0_0_data': lambda x: np.array(x)}, index_col=0).T`

Comment: From what I can tell, your column contains what appears to be lists. Could you be more specific on what the final result should look like?

Comment: @ap1997 Hi, please check my edit to see the expected result. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could pass a converter to `read_csv`. The `class_ 0_0_data` columns contains the string representation of lists of lists which can be parsed with `ast.literal_eval`. The hard part is that those lists can contain `nan` which will choke at `literal_eval`. A possible way is to enclose them in quotes to convert them into strings and them change them back to correct `np.nan` values:

```
def convert(x):
    x = x.replace("nan", "'nan'")
    lst = ast.literal_eval(x)
    lst = [[x if x != 'nan' else np.nan for x in i] for i in lst]
    return np.array(lst)
```

We should get a dataframe containing the expected np.ndarrays in its `class_ 0_0_data` column.

Once the dataframe is loaded, we can explode it, compute the row numbers with `groupby` and `cumcount`, and explode it again and compute the column numbers. Then a simple pivot should give the expected format:

```
df = pd.read_csv('class_ 0_0_data.csv',
                 converters={'class_ 0_0_data': convert})
df.columns = ['name', 'data']

df = df.explode('data')
df['row'] = df.groupby('name').cumcount()

df = df.explode('data')
df['col'] = df.groupby(['name', 'row']).cumcount()

df = df.pivot(index='row', columns=['name', 'col'], values='data').astype('float64')
```

In the end, we have a dataframe containing float64 columns with an initial part of (given by `df.head(10)`):

```
name CpuTemperature         ... ValidFrameOptrisPIIRCamera           
col               0      1  ...                          0          1
row                         ...                                      
0             56.75  44.75  ...                      259.0  27.582899
1             48.75  42.25  ...                      273.0  27.058227
2             47.50  42.00  ...                      272.0  26.907842
3             48.25  42.25  ...                      271.0  26.968238
4             50.00  42.50  ...                      271.0  26.969415
5             52.00  42.25  ...                      271.0  26.935518
6             50.00  40.50  ...                      270.0  26.886856
7             46.50  40.50  ...                      271.0  26.925594
8             47.75  41.00  ...                      271.0  26.975050
9             49.25  41.00  ...                      270.0  26.888554

[10 rows x 246 columns]
```

Comment: Thank you for answering! However, the output with and without converters are looking the same, and the data still has object datatype. How can I use the array data, for example, plotting?

Comment: @Gibran: The data in the second column are np.ndarrays, just see my edit which demonstrate it. It is certainly possible to transform it, but I do not know how to transform an array into a scalar float. You should show the expected result...

Comment: Hi, please check my edit to see the expected result. Thank you. @Serge

Comment: @Gibran: It was indeed more complex than my initial solution, but it should be correct now.

Comment: @Gibran: If it works, you should accept the answer (the check near it) to clearly show future readers that you no longer need help with this question.